# Prove that $[(\forall i | i>= 0 : P.i )\Rightarrow P.0]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have found this problem in $Programming - The derivation of algorithms":

$[(\forall i | i>= 0 : P.i )\Rightarrow P.0]$

I need help to interpret this kind of logical predicate. What does the hypothesis say (universal quantification) respect to the consequence?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking what the notation means, and why Edsger W. Dijkstra, Carel S. Scholten, et al. designed it in the first place, then please see [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html), which describes a slightly later version of that notation where Dijkstra would write $\;\langle \forall i : i \ge 0 : P.i \rangle\;$.

Most people would instead write the same statement something like this:
$$
(\forall i \ge 0, P(i)) \;\Rightarrow\;  P(0)
$$
In words: if $\;P\;$ holds for all non-negative $\;i\;$, then it also holds for $\;0\;$.

And the reason this statement is true, is because we can 'instantiate' the universal quantification in the antecedent with $\;i := 0\;$, leaving only the trivial proof obligation that $\;0 \ge 0\;$.